# Mobx with React, store made from class works but store made from function does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm following a simple counter tutorial to learn Mobx with react. This could be my lack of knowledge in javascript but I just can't seem to figure out why and if someone could help me understand why the functional store component is not working would be much appreciated.

When I make a store using class the counter works.

**myStore.js**

```
class myStore {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  count = 5;

  increment = () => {
    this.count++;
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.count--;
  }
}

export default new myStore();
```

but if I make the store as a function the value displays but the actions give an error saying "undefined has no properties". Mobx DevTool says "unnamed action".

```
const myStore = observable({
  count: 5,

  increment: action(() => {
    this.count++;
  }),

  decrement: action(() => {
    this.count--;
  }),
})

export default myStore;
```

Below are other parts of the code.

**Counter.jsx**

```
const Counter = inject('mystoreFromProvider')(
  observer(({ mystoreFromProvider }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={mystoreFromProvider.increment}>increase</button>
        <p>count is {mystoreFromProvider.count}</p>
        <button onClick={mystoreFromProvider.decrement}>decrement</button>
      </div>
    );
  })
);

export default Counter;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider mystoreFromProvider = {myStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
```

**Solved(Without really understanding)**

So after going through some more examples I got lucky and managed to get the functional store to work.
In the myStore.js I changed this

```
increment: action(() => {
    this.count++;
}),
```

to this

```
increment() {
    this.count++;
},
```

then in my Counter.js I changed this

```
<button onClick={mystoreFromProvider.increment}>increase</button>
```

to this, passing it as anonymous function

```
<button onClick={() => mystoreFromProvider.increment()}>increase</button>
```

and it's working.

Comment: you should try to use  "makeAutoObservable" as per docs : https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#makeobservable

Comment: I did for the class version. Is there a way to do it for the function version?